# Spring Data: getting list of objects with name methods

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Let's say

```
@Entity
public class Hospital {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Doctor> doctors;
    ...
}
```

How would I obtain a list of doctors in a specific hospital? I'v tried

```
public interface HospitalRepository extends Repository<Hospital, Long> {
    List<Doctor> findDoctorsById(Long hospitalId);
}
```

But suprisingly, it returns list of hospitals! Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to write the query yourself.

Comment: Yeah, of course I could do that, but wanted to use name methods. So you say it's definetely impossible then?

Comment: You cannot... You can only retrieve `Hospital`s you cannot use the queries to retrieve a property of a `Hospital`. You would have to write the query and put it on your method using a `@Query` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
Hospital h = hospitalRepository.findOne(Long id);
h.getDoctors():
```

or, if the hospital id is not primary key:

```
Hospital findByHospitalId(Long hospitalId);
```

Or if you want to return Doctor instances directly, put the query into Doctor repository (this expects a Hospital property in Doctor entity):

```
public interface DoctorRepository extends Repository<Doctor, Long> {
    List<Doctor> findByHospitalId(Long hospitalId);
}
```